# Accent insensitive collation for ð in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a dot net application that searches a SQL Server database, I use the collation Latin1_General_CI_AI to make the search query case and accent insensitive, this works 99.9% of the time. Is there a collation that enables me to match with ð? I'm sure there are other characters that don't work so it would be good to use one that covers everything.

```
select 1 as a where 'ð' = 'o' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
select 1 as a where 'ó' = 'o' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

output

| a |
| --- |
|  |

| a |
| --- |
| 1 |

Comment: `select 1 as a where 'ð' = 'd' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI`

Comment: This is correct, thank you.